# Count the entire number of rows in an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, row

So I have this query which gives me a list of id's and a count of how many times they are repeating in the particular table.  Though the table is quite large and I am having trouble figuring out how to count the number of rows the query is spitting back.

I tried a self join on the table and and 'IN' clause but couldn't get them to work

Any thoughts?

```
select id, count(*) as C 
from tblProduct
group by id 
having count(*) > 2
order by C desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from (select id, count(*) as C 
from tblProduct
group by id 
having count(*) > 2
) mytable
```

Comment: This comes up after that query

Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: my apologizes, i updated the query, hoping your rdbms is compatible with this kind of sql